# force-skip the Stripe connect account application form

Tags: oauth, stripe-payments

The Stripe [getting started guide](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started) suggests that you can force-skip the bank information form when testing your oAuth flow in development. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Before starting the oAuth flow, make sure you are using a development mode connected application key for the "client_id".  Then when you start the oAuth flow, you'll see [this banner](http://cl.ly/image/0x071V203k01) at the top of the account application form. Click on this link to skip the activation form.

Comment: Thanks David.  I had to log out of strip to see this.

Answer (score 2):

For other readers that might come here with this problem and if you see the login screen when trying to connect you need to:

- Click Sign Up - on the bottom of the page
- Click Skip this step - in the subtitle
- After that you will have the normal screen on in top right you will have Skip this account form"

I had this morning this problem and I manage to go back to the screen where I can skip doing so.